# How to test NotFound in WebAPI using xUNit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, xunit, autofixture

I am having a Web API method which is taking two inputs as `string` and returning output. I have performed below steps to to a unit testing using xUnit.

1. Created xUnit project and added one method to it.
2. Creating a mock data using `AutoFixure`.
3. Added test code and running the test **without running** **API project**. Am I doing this right here? Do I need to run API project as well?
4. My test is giving me result instead of NoDataFound. When I am running a test case from Postman, I am getting expected `404 error` but in xUnit, getting object with count 3.

I am not sure where and what I am missing. Any help please. TIA.
Below is my code.

````
public class ControllerTest
{
    private readonly IFixture fixure;
    private readonly Mock<ICustomerService> service;;
    private readonly CustController  controller;

    public CustControllerTest()
    {
        service = new Mock<ICustomerService>();
        controller = new CustController(service.Object);
        fixure = new Fixture();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetMember_WithZeroAsInput_ShouldReturnNotFound()

    {

        //arrange
            var member = fixure.Create<List<Member>>();//creating a mock for Member object
            var Id = Convert.ToString(0); //0 as input
            var name = Convert.ToString(0);//0 as input

            service.Setup(x => x.GetMember(Id, name)).ReturnsAsync(member);//here I am getting 3 record count even my both inputs are 0

            //act
            var result = await CustController.GetMember(Id, name);//here also I am getting 3 record count even my both inputs are 0.
                //when I am calling GetMember from Postman with 0 as inputs I am getting NotFound result. 

            //assert
            result.Should().NotBeNull();
            result.Result.Should().BeAssignableTo<NotFoundObjectResult>();//getting error here as - Expected memberFlagResult.Result to be assignable to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundObjectResult, but Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult is not.
            result.Verify(x => x.GetMember(memberId, flagName), Times.Once());
        
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from the line `var member = fixture.Create<List<Member>>();`

the `fixture.Create` will generate an anonymous object (https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture#overview) to solve your problem you should be more explicit => `var member = null` or `var member = new List<Member>()` depending if you are expected `null` or an empty list in your controller to return the `404`.

Comment: When I changed the  line to var member = new List<Member>();   from  var member = fixture.Create<List<Member>>(); I am getting the error as  --   Expected result.Result to be assignable to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundObjectResult, but Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult is not.

Comment: As I said, you need to set the `member` variable depending on what you are expecting in your controller to return your `404`, if you have the logic `if(members != null) return Ok()` then you'll not have the `404` expected if you set `var member = new List<Member>()` you should set the `List<Member> member = null` instead. You need to look at the code in your controller :)